# NPM dependencies caret (^)

Tags: r, npm, dependencies, version, r-caret

Suppose I published two packages on NPM:

```
a (0.1.0)
b (0.1.0) 
  `-- a (^0.1.0)
```

if I have this `package.json` in my project:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "a": "^0.1.0",
    "b": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

after launching `npm install` in the `node_modules/` I find these two folders:

```
node_modules/a (0.1.0)
node_modules/b (0.1.0)
```

If at this point I create a version `a` (0.2.0) and update the `package.json` of my project:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "a": "^0.2.0",
    "b": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

after launching `npm install` in the `node_modules/` I find the folders

```
node_modules/a (0.2.0)
node_modules/b (0.1.0)
    node_modules/
        a (0.1.0)
```

Why this thing?

Being specified in the `package.json` of the project `b` a dependency on `a` (`^0.1.0`), when I update on the project `a` to 0.2.0, why the project `b` don't take the correct dependency to `a` version 0.2.0?

I don't want to specify *latest* as dependency rule.

Comment: What happens if you delete `node_modules/` and start over? The dependency on `b` is already met, so it won't be reinstalled.

Comment: I try to remove **node_modules/** folder and **package-lock.json** and after exec **npm install**, but i have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run an `npm update` or reinstall your `node_modules` i.e.

1. `npm update`

or

2. `rm -rf node_modules
    npm i`

Comment: I try to remove **node_modules/** folder and **package-lock.json** and after exec **npm install**, but i have the same result.